# Regular expression for text only from integers separated by newline characters

Tags: regex

There is the following regular expression:

```
^[1-9]\d{0,8}[\r\n]?$
```

It describes one line of text.

How to indicate that this expression is applicable to 1 or more lines of text? I do not exclude that changes will be required in the above expression.

Comment: Why is there `\r?\n` in your expression? I do not really understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ou have a `^[line_pattern]$` regex. To expand it to validate a multiline string where each line shouldmeet the same `[line_pattern]` use `^[line_pattern](?:\r?\n[line_pattern])*$`. In some engines that support the `\R` line break regex construct, replace `\r?\n` with it.

You may use

```
^[1-9]\d{0,8}(?:\r?\n[1-9]\d{0,8})*$
```

or

```
^[1-9]\d{0,8}(?:\R[1-9]\d{0,8})*$
```

It matches

- `^` - start of a string
- `[1-9]\d{0,8}` - a non-zero digit followed with 0 to 8 any digits
- `(?:\r?\n[1-9]\d{0,8})*` - 0 or more repetitions of

  - `\r?\n` - a CRLF or an LF only line ending (`\R` matches any line break sequence)
  - `[1-9]\d{0,8}` - a non-zero digit followed with 0 to 8 any digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: This also works more correctly: `^[1-9]\d{0,8}(?:\r\n[1-9]\d{0,8})*$`

Comment: @Anton It is just forces line endings to CRLF. Just choose the line endings as per your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression was for a single line. I have simply changed your expression to say there will be one or more of them using parentheses and a plus to indicate 'one or more'.

I have also edited the way you defend the end of the line. I am assuming that there is always a CRLF or LF at the end of each number:

```
^([1-9]\d{0,8}\r?\n)+$
```

Comment: The regexps of the `^(ab?)+$` type must be avoided as they lead to [catastrophic backtracking](https://regex101.com/r/w6uKvU/1).

Comment: `^([1-9]\d{0,8}[\r\n]?)+$` it doesn’t work because character limit is not taken into account `{0,8}`

Comment: Edited; but I don't see an issue with the character count

Comment: This doesn't work if the last line have no linebreak.